# How to run Collabnet Subverion 1.7 and 1.8 side-by-side on the same machine?

Tags: svn, dll, collabnet

For some research purpose, I wish to install Collabnet Subverion 1.7 and 1.8 on the same Windows machine, but encounter some weird problem.

I use Collabnet official installer, with their digital signature:

- CollabNetSubversion-client-1.7.10-1-Win32.exe (2013)
- CollabNetSubversion-client-1.8.11-1-Win32.exe (2015)

I first install 1.7, and run it without problem. Then I install 1.8, and when asked whether to upgrade, I answer No, to install it to a different folder.

[image: Snap1335-collabnet-svn-upgrade-NO.png]

When 1.8 install finishes, I open a CMD window, explicitly remove 1.7's folder from PATH. Now the problem comes, `svn --version` reports many DLL entry point failure. Analyzing the svn.exe process reveals that DLLs from both **C:\CollabNet-svn-1.7** and **C:\CollabNet-svn-1.8** are loaded into the process, which is abnormal.

Why do 1.7's DLL get loaded and how to fix this behavior?

[image: Snap1334-svn1.7-1.8-coexist-fail.png]

Trying on Windows Server 2003.